# Palindromic Residue

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, palindrome

Today, as I'm writing this, is March 31st. In the US, this is `3/31`. I was playing around with `331` as a number to come up with a challenge, and found that its residues (modulo small numbers) is palindromic. `331%2=1, 331%3=1, 331%4=3, 331%5=1, 331%6=1` (`11311`).

Your challenge here is, when given an integer `n > 2`, output the first `n` positive numbers that have palindromic residue when taken modulo `[2,n]`.

For example, for input `7`, the output should be `1, 42, 43, 140, 182, 420, 421`. Here's the chart explaining why that's the case:

```
        mod
num | 2 3 4 5 6 7
-----------------
  1 | 1 1 1 1 1 1
 42 | 0 0 2 2 0 0
 43 | 1 1 3 3 1 1
140 | 0 2 0 0 2 0
182 | 0 2 2 2 2 0
420 | 0 0 0 0 0 0
421 | 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

### Input

A single positive integer `n` with `n > 2` [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).

### Output

The resulting array/list of the first `n` palindromic residues, as outlined above. Again, in any suitable format.

### Rules

- For `n > 10`, assume the residue list to be flattened before checking whether it's a palindrome. That is, `[1, 10, 11]` is palindromic, but `[1, 10, 1]` is not.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

#### Examples

```
[input]
[output]

3
[1, 6, 7]

4
[1, 4, 5, 8]

5
[1, 50, 60, 61, 110]

6
[1, 30, 31, 60, 61, 90]

7
[1, 42, 43, 140, 182, 420, 421]

8
[1, 168, 169, 336, 337, 504, 505, 672]

9
[1, 2520, 2521, 5040, 5041, 7560, 7561, 10080, 10081]

10
[1, 280, 281, 560, 1611, 1890, 1891, 2170, 2171, 2241]

11
[1, 22682, 27720, 27721, 50402, 55440, 55441, 78122, 83160, 83161, 105842]
```

Comment: Is the output supposed to be ordered?

Comment: @Arnauld It doesn't need to be, no, provided that it includes only the first `n` elements.

Comment: arrgh ... your challenge = your rules, but "`[1, 10, 11]` is palindromic, but `[1, 10, 1]` is not" seems so mathematically wrong.

Comment: @GregMartin Stringy palindromes, not mathy palindromes. ;-)

Comment: Can you add a test case that makes use of the `n>10` flattening behaviour?

Comment: @math_junkie I don't have a full test case, but for an example, `15` has this happen when it gets to `1041040` -- the residues are `0 1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 10`.

Comment: grr. The whole stringy instead of mathy palindrome makes this a thousand times harder in certain languages. Oh well.

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 57 bytes

```
f n=take n[x|x<-[1..],(==)=<<reverse$show.mod x=<<[2..n]]
```

Usage example: `f 4` -> `[1,4,5,8]`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mkGdbkpidqpAXXVFTYaMbbainF6ujYWuraWtjU5RallpUnKpSnJFfrpebn6JQARSMNtLTy4uN/Z@bmJmnYKtQUJSZV6KgopCmYGjwHwA)

The first `=<<` is in function context and translates to the lambda `\x -> reverse x == x` and the second `=<<` is in list context and equivalent to `concatMap`, i.e. map-and-flatten-one-list-level.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
µN2¹Ÿ%JÂQD½–
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@39oq5/RoZ1Hd6h6HW4KdDm091HD5P//DQ0A)

**Explanation**

```
µ              # until counter equals input do:
 N             # push current iterations number
     %         # modulus each in
  2¹Ÿ          # range [2 ... input]
      J        # joined to string
       ÂQ      # equals it's reverse
         D     # duplicate
          ½    # if true, increase counter
           –   # if true print iteration number
```

Comment: Do you post 05AB1E answers from your phone? Cause you do these quick lol.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Very seldom as a lot of the characters in cp-1252 are annoying to type/copy-paste on the phone. This one popped up right before I checked my computer after dinner, so I had pretty good timing :)

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 79 bytes

```
NestList[#+1//.x_/;!PalindromeQ[ToString/@Mod[x,Range@n+1]<>""]:>x+1&,1,n=#-1]&
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>98</s> 97 bytes

```py
n=input();i=j=0
while i<n:
 j+=1;l=''
 for k in range(2,n+1):l+=`j%k`
 if l==l[::-1]:i+=1;print j
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RVFdb4MwDHzPr/BUTW3VTopDAoEuv2J7q5D6FdZQFCpgqvbrOzto2suZnO/iM3lGF@L9e1qtd8G1TorHNXQewnusBLQbh7vOLZcCmn6AG4QIwzF@@ZXaxg2uq27jDu3r7SAgNNA51@2r6g3rKrDxPoQ4Qft8olrA5zWM0Ee/HGEawvn28yIQF3vcglK5VVSKQsm5EGmklkQao7WcC5GFRUWkzTCXcyESpbFa1SJLl@WkqoVO35qMJKuFSUdDHvYlE8pa5InOiMrwv1VSp5j9NEtnJOYIyBk1J9QKa2GTAnPLUNINWc5QpOQMNDkvKFY572jSbuZvtYS8keGxhGkRaeVcaADK2ciUsmxjJW3MSlumRCULsJAJ05/U5FzAxyNM5yv0w8UPMPUw@XGCS2iaxg@enuR8HP2OXsRT886PAo/QdXDySekvvw)

Comment: [you can drop the entire string conversion](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RVBBbsIwELz7FSuhSiCo5HVsxwnNK9ob8oGCAw6Rg0Iqnk93bVW9zCbjGe@MX6mL6f6zrDf72A2dFM9rHAPEj9QKGLYd7sfuMLzdoJ9muEFMMB/TJazVLm1x4wXEHsauGw9t@46@jey4zzEtMLxeiKsD7kAp6xSNulayDCKN1JJIY7SWZRBZO1REugqtLINIlMZp5UWVL7Ok8kLnb01Gknlh8q8hD/uyCaUXNtMVURX@HzV0Uhc/7dIViTkCckbNCbVCL1xWoHUMDd1QWYY6J2egzbamWE3paHI381ctIzcyvJYwF5FOlkELUBYjU8qxjZXUmJWuyYkaFmAtM@aX1ORcweczLqcrTPM5zLBMsITHAufY932YA7396fgIe/i6Bjq8w5QCPOM4wnfIynD@BQ "Python 2 – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @Rod Thanks, but I believe that would fail on input `12` due to the strange rule that `[1, 10, 11]` is considered a palindrome

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 104 bytes

```js
f=(n,x=(k=--n,2))=>k?([...Array(n)].map(_=>(r=x%++i+r,x%i),i=1,r='').join``==r?k--&&x+' ':'')+f(n,x+1):1
```

#### Demo

**NB**: Because of the numerous recursive calls, this will crash for *n > 8* on Firefox or *n > 10* on Chrome.

```js
f=(n,x=(k=--n,2))=>k?([...Array(n)].map(_=>(r=x%++i+r,x%i),i=1,r='').join``==r?k--&&x+' ':'')+f(n,x+1):1

for(n = 2; n < 9; n++) {
  console.log(n, '=>', f(n));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 19 bytes

*Thanks to @AdmBorkBork for pointing out a mistake in an earlier version of the code, now corrected*

```
`@Gq:Q\VXztP=?@]NG<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5/g4F5oFRgTFlFVEmBr7xDr527z/785AA)

#### Explanation

```
`        % Do...while
  @      %   Push iteration index, starting at 1
  Gq:Q   %   Push [2 3 ... n], where n is the input
  \      %   Modulo, element-wise
  V      %   Convert to string. Numbers are separated by spaces
  Xz     %   Remove spaces
  tP     %   Duplicate, flip
  =      %   Equal? (element-wise)
  ?      %   If all results were true
    @    %     Push current iteration index. It is one of the sought numbers
  ]      %   End
  N      %   Push number of elements in stack
  G      %   Push input n
  <      %   Less than? This is the loop condition
         % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, <strike>90</strike> <strike>86</strike> 82 bytes

```
(n:Int)=>Stream.from(1)filter{i=>val d=(2 to n)map(i%)mkString;d.reverse==d}take(n)
```

### Explanation

```
Stream.from(1)                              // From an infinite Stream starting from 1,
    filter ( i => {                         // keep only elements matching the next condition :
        val d=(2 to n)map(i%)mkString;      // Generate residues and convert to String,
        d.reverse==d                        // return true if palindrom, false otherwise
    })take(n)                               // Finally, take the n first elements matching the condition
```

### Test cases

```
val f = (n:Int)=>...    // assign function
(3 to 11).foreach { i =>
    println(i + "\n" + f(i).mkString(", ") + "\n")
}
```

### Results

```
3
1, 6, 7

4
1, 4, 5, 8

5
1, 50, 60, 61, 110

6
1, 30, 31, 60, 61, 90

7
1, 42, 43, 140, 182, 420, 421

8
1, 168, 169, 336, 337, 504, 505, 672

9
1, 2520, 2521, 5040, 5041, 7560, 7561, 10080, 10081

10
1, 280, 281, 560, 1611, 1890, 1891, 2170, 2171, 2241

11
1, 22682, 27720, 27721, 50402, 55440, 55441, 78122, 83160, 83161, 105842
```

### Edits

#### #1 (90 => 86)

- anonymous function

#### #2 (86 => 82)

- remove useless dot characters after parenthesis or bracket (ex. : `(2 to n).map(%i)` => `(2 to n)map(%i)`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if I could change `def f(n:Int)=` to `(n:Int)=>`, since it also defines a function (but without name). It saves 4 bytes !

Comment: Yes, [unnamed functions are allowed](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/should-function-literals-be-allowed-when-a-function-is-asked-for/1503#1503), provided you don't need the name for a recursive call or something like that.

Comment: Great, edited :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
%Ð€ḊDFŒḂ
1ç#
```

#### How?

```
1ç# - Main link: n
1   - initialise "i" at 1
  # - increment i and yield a list of the first n truthful results of:
 ç  -     last link (1) as a dyad

%Ð€ḊDFŒḂ - Link 1, test a value "i" for mod [2,n] being palindromic: i, n
 Ð€      - for each, mapped over the right argument, i.e. for j = 1 to n:
%        -     i modulo j
   Ḋ     - dequeue, i.e. discard the modulo 1 result
    D    - convert to decimal list (vectorises)
     F   - flatten into one list
      ŒḂ - is palindromic?
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ARsA5P//JcOQ4oKs4biKREbFkuG4ggoxw6cj////MTI)**

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 93 Bytes

```
for(;$x<$a=$argn;$s="")for($i=1,++$n;$i++<$a;)if($i==$a&strrev($s.=$n%$i)==$s)echo$n._.!++$x;
```

[Online Version 2 Loops Output as string](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fce023b1ce442f329e1ccf2721b8e50831e2d75c)

Expanded

```
for(;$x<$a=$argn;$s="") 
for($i=1,++$n;$i++<$a;)
    if($i==$a&strrev($s.=$n%$i)==$s)echo$n._.!++$x;
```

### PHP 130 Bytes

```
for(;count($r)<$a=$argn;$s=[])for($i=1,++$n;$i++<$a;){$s[]=$n%$i;if(count($s)==$a-1&strrev($j=join($s))==$j)$r[]=$n; }print_r($r);
```

[Online Version 2 Loops](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/37e785610cbf824a03282c672a2c53474dca6cb0)

Expanded

```
for(;count($r)<$a=$argn;$s=[])
for($i=1,++$n;$i++<$a;){
    $s[]=$n%$i;
    if(count($s)==$a-1&strrev($j=join($s))==$j)$r[]=$n; 
}
print_r($r);
```

### PHP, 139 Bytes with 1 loop

```
for($i=$n=1;count($r)<($a=$argn)&$i++<$a;){$s[]=$n%$i;if(count($s)==$a-1){if(strrev($j=join($s))==$j)$r[]=$n;$n++;$s=[];$i=1;}}print_r($r);
```

[Online Version 1 Loop](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6de6663864590c57de859f3bc32f1fb0a28db5d)

Run with

```
echo '<string>' | php -nR '<code>'
```

Expanded

```
for($i=$n=1;count($r)<($a=$argn)&$i++<$a;){
    $s[]=$n%$i;
    if(count($s)==$a-1){
        if(strrev($j=join($s))==$j)$r[]=$n;
        $n++;
        $s=[];
        $i=1;
    }
}
print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 1):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 28 bytes

```
0ri:N{{)_N),2>f%s_W%#}g_p}*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@29QlGnlV12tGe@nqWNkl6ZaHB@uqlybHl9Qq2X9/7@hIQA)

#### Explanation

```
0          e# Push 0, the value we'll repeatedly increment to search for valid outputs.
ri:N       e# Read input, convert to integer, store in N.
{          e# Run this block N times...
  {        e#   Run this block until the condition is true, which will find the next
           e#   number with palindromic residues...
    )_     e#     Increment and duplicate.
    N),2>  e#     Push [2 3 ... N].
    f%     e#     Take the current value modulo each of these.
    s      e#     Flatten them into a single string.
    _W%    e#     Duplicate and reverse.
    #      e#     Try to find the reverse in the original. A common way to compute
           e#     "not equal" for strings of the same length.
  }g
  _p       e#   Print a copy of the result.
}*
;          e# Discard the final result to prevent printing it twice.
```

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 48 bytes

```
:{A=G[2,a|A=A+!q%b$]~A=_fA||h=h+1?q]q=q+1~h=a|_X
```

Beats Mathematica! Sample run:

```
Command line: 10
 1 
 280 
 281 
 560 
 1611 
 1890 
 1891 
 2170 
 2171 
 2241
```

Explanation:

```
:{          Get 'a' from the command line, start an inf. loop
A=G         Clear out whatever's in A$
[2,a|       For each of the numbers we want to modulo
A=A+        Add to A$ 
     q%b       our current number MODULO te loop iterator
    !   $      cast to string
]           NEXT
~A=_fA|     If the string of remainders is a palindrome (_f ... | is Reverse())
|h=h+1      THEN h=h+1 (h starts at 0) - this counts how many hits we've had
 ?q            also, print the number with the palindromic remainder
]           END IF
q=q+1       Test the next number
~h=a|_X     If we've had 'a' hits, quit.
            The last IF and the infinite loop are closed implicitly.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 26 bytes

```
L³o fR{C=Uò2@R%XÃ¬ ¥CwÃj1U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@@9zaHO@QlpQtbNt6OFNRg5BqhGHmw@tUTi01Ln8cHOWYej//xYA) Takes a few seconds on *all* inputs, so be patient please.

This would be considerably shorter (and faster) if there were a built-in to get the first N numbers satisfying some condition:

```
R{C=Uò2@R%XÃ¬ ¥Cw}aU
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
1%ⱮḊŒḂɗ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef8Kw4fGrP8xJeKxruG4isWS4biCyZcj////MTE)

### How it works

```
1%ⱮḊŒḂɗ# - Main link. Takes n on the left
1        - Set the return value to 1
       # - Count up i = 1, 2, ..., and return the first n which return true:
      ɗ  -   Combine the previous three links into a dyad
             with i on the left and n on the right:
  Ɱ      -     For each integer m in 1, 2, ..., n:
 %       -       i % m
   Ḋ     -     Remove i % 1
    ŒḂ   -     Is palindromic?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@õ!uX ÅêS}jU1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QPUhdVggxepTfWpVMQ&input=Nw) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QPUhdVggxepTfWpVMQ&input=WzMsNCw1LDYsNyw4LDksMTAsMTFdCi1tUg)

```
@õ!uX ÅêS}jU1     :Implicit input of integer U
@                 :Function taking an integer X as argument
 õ                :  Range [1,U]
  !uX             :  Mod X by each
      Å           :  Slice off the first
       êS         :  Is palindrome?
         }        :End function
          jU1     :Starting with 1, return the first U integers that return true
```